# Link field type displaying '&' as '&amp;'

Tags: navigation

When I have a Link title field populated with '&' it will be displayed as '&' when rendered.

I have done a fair share of google searching but haven't quite nailed it down.

I was thinking this was a start in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/a/5019423

Drupal 7.19 with a zen subtheme

visual -

rendered https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cEbj.jpg

on form https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWe9X.jpg

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) passes the text through [check_plain](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/check_plain/7) which escapes the HTML characters for display.

So, there's no need to double escape the link with another check_plain later.

Pass the raw text, including the single "&" through as the link text and output it as such, that way it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @David Thomas, Okay so I scrapped the idea of using l() . How exactly would I output the link text as raw text?

Comment: You should use l() to create the link, but make sure the input text is raw, with the single "&"

Comment: I'm sorry, I need that dumbed down. It looks to me that link.module creates the link with l() and the text is raw(unformatted?) and with a single & on the form. As seen in the screenshot.

Comment: sorry @David Thomas ^

Comment: You may need to provide more information, i.e the whole stack from when the text is input to output, and the related functions.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Link module fixed this for me. Although I'm sure @David Thomas' answer would fix the issue as well.